# Schengen Type C Visa Field 18 Residence in a country other than the country of current nationality

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm Chinese citizen travel by chinese passport currently hold an Australian PR and apply for Schengen visa. Field 18 ask

**Residence in a country other than the country of current nationality: No Yes. Residence permit or equivalent ................. No. ................... Valid until .................**

My answer is Yes. Then I'm confused about what to fill in. Should I put in my vise class / subclass and visa grant No.?

Comment: You would put in the no of your Australia PR and its valid to date, assuming you are not Australian citizen of course

Comment: @MattDouhan I don't know about Australia specifically, but generally countries do not grant permanent resident status to their own citizens.

Comment: @phoog Agreed but it was not clear in the question so just putting a caveat in there

Comment: I'm Chinese citizen travel by chinese passport. I guess I should answer Yes here

Comment: @MattDouhan would you add an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visa subclass and grant number seem perfectly reasonable to include as the numbers for the Schengen visa application form.

You can also print a copy of [proof of permanent residence](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/permanent-resident/evidence-of-residency-status) from [VEVO](https://online.immi.gov.au/evo/firstParty?actionType=query) and include it with your Schengen visa application. This will remove all doubt and allow the consulate to verify your permanent resident status.